# How do I script such that my panoramic image can be panned left and right up to its edges?

Tags: javascript, html, css, panoramas

Say my image (panoramic) is 10,000 pixels long, but I want to be able to view only 1000 pixels wide at a time, and in order to view more of it, I can just hover my mouse either left or right, and then the image will move accordingly please? If possible, a simple script on HTML? (I'm not sure how to use Javascript or CSS, but if it needs to come down to that, do guide me step by step?

Thank you.

Comment: If you would search on google you would find photo gallery for panorama pictures pretty easly. Try to search before posting things here.

Comment: I did. I took a few hours and still could not get what I wanted. Some of the results are a bit confusing for a layman like me. That's why I came here hoping for people to be able to guide me... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple JQuery which you can use to scroll the whole page when hovering over either the left or right;

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/38da9pca/

Need any help implementing it just leave a comment and I will try and help you.

```
$(function() {
                $('#right').on('mouseenter', rscroll);
                $('#left').on('mouseenter', lscroll);
                $('#right, #left').on('mouseleave', function() {
                    $('body').stop();
                });

                function rscroll() {
                    $('body').animate({
                        scrollLeft: '+=25'
                    }, 10, rscroll);
                }

                function lscroll() {
                    $('body').animate({
                        scrollLeft: '-=25'
                    }, 10, lscroll);
                }
            });
```

**Edit (Scroll Image Only)**

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/38da9pca/1/

I have change it so the lscroll and the rscroll will effect the id of image instead of the body and change it from scrollLeft to left, and that way it will move the images scroll. **Dont forgot to change the `$('body').stop();` to `$('#bg').stop();` or it will never stop scrolling**

```
$(function() {
                $('#right').on('mouseenter', rscroll);
                $('#left').on('mouseenter', lscroll);
                $('#right, #left').on('mouseleave', function() {
                    $('#bg').stop();
                });

                function rscroll() {
                    $('#bg').animate({
                        left: '-=25'
                    }, 10, rscroll);
                }

                function lscroll() {
                    $('#bg').animate({
                        left: '+=25'
                    }, 10, lscroll);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Hmmm rather than scroll a whole page, I was hoping the page remains static, and the image is confined within a certain dimension, but you can scroll right and left as long as you hover the mouse on either the right or the left side of the image. Anything like that?^^

Comment: @Silv ofcourse, I will quickly update my answer now for you!

Comment: @Silv I have updated the answer, the new code is at the bottom with a new JSFiddle example, anymore help let me kow

Comment: @Silv haha just realised that is is scrolling in the opposite way, just change rscroll from '-=25' to '+=25' and lscroll from '+=25' to '-=25' that should flip it and make it work for you,

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying~ I'm gonna have to bother you a bit more and ask where do I apply these functions to? And how do I apply these functions to my image >_<? (this is what happens when le powers above think a multimedia designer can program :< )

Comment: @Silv There are a few ways you can link it, you can either link it at the bottom of the page in <script>functions goes here</script> or what I do to make the page less messy is to put it into a .js file and link it once again at the bottom of the page like, <script src="functions/imagescroller.js"></script>. Don't forgot to link Jquery in the document as well or it won't work :) easy mistake I do it all the time and spend ages working out why it isn't working

Comment: @Silv If you get it all working please can you mark my the question as answered so people know that the problem is solved, thank you, anything more problems you have, just let me know and i will try and help!

Comment: Haha, it's not working yet... Please bear with me...>_< For the script, put it in <body>? <head>? And how do I link Jquery?

Comment: I typically would link it in the body just before </body>. Frist link your jQuery link so; <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> the link your function <script></script>

Comment: I dare say I screwed something up :x It scrolls either way, but keeps scrolling until the pic is out of the screen as long as my mouse is over the button, but as you mentioned earlier, the $('body').stop(); has been changed to $('#bg').stop(); so o.O

Comment: @Silv here you go, just download the file from here, I have cleaned up some of your tags, for example your body was being close before it even opened :)  https://github.com/Matthammond96/StackOver/blob/master/scroll.html

Comment: Thanks so much! I removed the file because I realised I screwed up a number of things like that hehe >_<. Now the only thing left is the scrolling until out of screen image :)  (I'm so sorry for causing so much problems) Is there a way to stop the image once it reaches it's edges? (It's alright if there isn't....)

Comment: @Silv Im also new to Jquery, so I can't seem to work out how to track the position as it is using .animate, I have posted a question so if I get an answer I will let you know :) to see the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993740/how-to-track-animate-left-position

Comment: @Silv haha its ok Im digital media designer and I get expected to code all the time so I thought I best teach myself, still leaning :)

Comment: I'd usually draw the line between designing and scripting, but some things can't be avoided sometimes...

Comment: @Silv Haha, also they have worked out the problem, if you go to that link I sent a few comments back and use either code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one. It's using jquery (javascript library). You would have to add it in order to make it work.

Example:
http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/jqueryphotonav/

Tutorial:
https://blog.gaya.ninja/articles/jquery-convertion-panoramic-photoviewer-in-javascript/

Comment: I did find this one, but the tutorial is a broken link :/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var imgView = document.querySelectorAll('.img-view')[0];
var img = imgView.querySelectorAll('img')[0];

imgView.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  
  var px = ((x / this.offsetWidth) * 100);
  
  var ix = ((px / 100) * img.offsetWidth);
  
  img.style.left = '-' + (ix - this.offsetWidth) + 'px';
}
```

```css
.img-view {
  width: 256px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.img-view img {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-view">
  <img src="http://panoramalove.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/nighttime-panoramic-view-of-hong-kong-island-from-the-avenue-of-stars-in-tsim-sha-tsui.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. In which parts of my html do I apply the codes, please?