# How to track .animate left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have this JQuery which will move a div left and right when hovered on the left and right buttons, however I need it to stop when the image position is at 0px;

My current code - https://jsfiddle.net/38da9pca/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#right').on('mouseenter', rscroll);
    $('#left').on('mouseenter', lscroll);
    $('#right, #left').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#bg').stop();
    });

    function rscroll() {
        $('#bg').animate({
            left: '-=25'
        }, 10, rscroll);
    }

    function lscroll() {
        $('#bg').animate({
            left: '+=25'
        }, 10, lscroll);
    }
});
```

However I can't seem to track the `#bg` left positon. I have tired `.position().left` and `.offset().left` and both of them give a static result when `console.log();` instead of dymically changing whilst scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have to check whether the element is already touching its boundaries

- If it is, do nothing
- If not, check if the next change is will go past the boundaries

  - If it will, only move by the remaining distance.
  - If it wont, move by `25` pixels

Also, you should cache your jQuery objects for better performance as I've done here.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/38da9pca/13/))

```
$(function() {
    var bg = $('#bg'), left, maxLeft, maxRight;
    $('#right').on('mouseenter', rscroll);
    $('#left').on('mouseenter', lscroll);
    $('#right, #left').on('mouseleave', function() {
        bg.stop();
    });

    function rscroll() {
        maxRight = (bg.width() - $(window).width()) * -1;
        left = bg.position().left;
        if(left > maxRight) {
            bg.animate({
                left: '-=' + (left + 25 > maxRight ? 25 : left)
            }, 10, rscroll);
        }
    }

    function lscroll() {
        maxLeft = bg.width() - $(window).width();
        left = bg.position().left;
        if(left < 0) {
            bg.animate({
                left: '+=' + (maxLeft - left > 25 ? 25 : left)
            }, 10, lscroll);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/38da9pca/4/

This works by saying only animate if it hasn't scrolled further than its width - window inner width

and for left if it has not scrolled past 0.

```
$(function () {
    var bg = $('#bg');
    $('#right').on('mouseenter', rscroll);
    $('#left').on('mouseenter', lscroll);
    $('#right, #left').on('mouseleave', function () {
        bg.stop();
    });

    function rscroll() {
        if (bg.position().left * -1 > bg.width() - $(window).innerWidth()) {
            bg.stop();
            return;
        }
        bg.animate({
            left: '-=25'
        }, 10, rscroll);
    }

    function lscroll() {
        if (bg.position().left > 0) {
            bg.stop();
            return;
        }
        bg.animate({
            left: '+=25'
        }, 10, lscroll);
    }
});
```